# nvd3 legends overlap

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

My data contains two curves which are rendered correctly, yet the legends overlap such that the coloured dot and text for the second partially overlap the text for the first. When I click either dot to hide a curve, the overlap resolves immediately, and does not return.

Code below. There are multiple of these on a page.  When I omit the xAxis line, the issue resolves, though there is no obvious connection.

```
d3.json('project_x_data.json', function(data) {
  nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
                  .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                  .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
                  .clipEdge(true);

  chart.xAxis.axisLabel('').tickFormat(function(d){
    return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%y')(new Date(d*1000)) });

  d3.select('#chart-project_x_data svg').datum(data)
    .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
  return chart;
  });
});
```

Versions:: Browsers: Firefox, Chrome, on Ubuntu and OSX. Same behaviour on 
novus/nvd3 latest, and Advael's current merges.

Edit...

The charts are included on a bootstrap tab that is not displayed by default as the page loads. When I resize the browser window when the tab **IS** selected (charts are visible visible) the legends correct themselves. When I resized the browser window when the tab is **NOT** selected (charts are hidden), **then** select the tab, the legends have not corrected themselves.  Since the chart is soooo... simple, the issue seems to be that the render is done while the chart is hidden.

Does this help provoke any thoughts?

Comment: FYI - I have this problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue anymore.

I now render the graphs using Ajax, only when the tab has become visible.  This is enough to make the result reliable and repeatable.